# Getting a MySql Select FLOOR(rand) AS into a PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql

Im a PHP newbie and im trying to figure out the best way to get random_num in the following code into a PHP variable.

```
$query = "SELECT FLOOR(rand(0, 28000) as random_num
     FROM numbers_mst 
     WHERE random_num NOT IN (SELECT random_num FROM numbers_mst)
     LIMIT 1";

$mysqli->query($query);
```

Sorry if this is simple, i've tried all sorts of syntax variations and googled the hell out of it but I can only find how to get row results into variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL won't do what you want in a single query. You need to iterate your query to get the unique number:

```
do {
    $random = rand(0, 28000);
    $query = "SELECT numbers FROM numbers_mst
              WHERE numbers = $random LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
} while ($result->num_rows > 0);
```

This way you can use $random as your unique random number as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetch_row` or `fetch_object` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

So your code will be:

```
$query = "SELECT FLOOR(rand(0, 28000)) as random_num
FROM numbers_mst 
WHERE random_num NOT IN (SELECT numbers FROM numbers_mst)
LIMIT 1";

$result = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_object()->random_num; // This will contain your number
```

While your at it, also read the other functions, in case you want to go further with multiple results:

`mysqli_fetch_array()` - Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` - Fetch a result row as an associative array

`mysqli_fetch_object()` - Returns the current row of a result set as an object

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, i'm on shared hosting so I just get a server 500 error... Any ideas?